# Can jsonschema2pojo be used to generate classes from json-schema at runtime and instantiate objects from them?

Tags: java, reflection, jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

Is there an end-to-end example of using jsonschema2pojo that does the following

1. Generate classes from types defined via json-schema
2. Load the class dynamically
3. Instantiate objects from such a class
4. Populate fields in the object